# Is there any way to convert a resource file path to a string and use it?

Tags: string, android-studio, filepath, android-resources

I want to have multiple paths be selected dynamicall in my app, and I was wondering if there is any way you can use a String to identify a file path into the res folder. For example, if I am trying to use an InputStream on a specific text file, I would use this code:

```
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile);
```

Is there any way to use a String as a replacement for R.raw.textfile?

Comment: You can use the `Resources#getIdentifier()` method to get the `int` value to use in place of the `R.raw.textfile`. The linked duplicate is asking about an audio file there, but it's the exact same thing for any `raw` resource.

Comment: Also, the proper tag to use for general Android programming questions is just [android]. The [android-studio] tag is for questions specifically concerning the IDE.